# Where does a C# program look for a DLL?

Tags: c#, c, dll

I wrote a very simple C# program that opens a DLL. There are two projects ... (1) a project being a C function built as a DLL and (2) the C# program that uses the DLL.

The C# program has the following line:

```
[DllImport("C_dll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
```

But when I run it doesn't find the DLL.

Since the build shows the DLL here:

```
"W:\Dropbox\DSI (His)\Windows Apps\Debug\C_dll.dll"
```

I changed the DllImport to:

```
[DllImport("W:\\Dropbox\\DSI (His)\\Windows Apps\\Debug\\C_dll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
```

And, of course, it runs. But I want the location to be relative. So I tried these paths:

```
[DllImport("..\\..\\..\\Debug\\C_dll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    (that is relative to where the projects are)
    and
[DllImport("Debug\\C_dll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    (that is relative to where the solution is)
```

To check my relative paths I did some dirs:

```
W:\Dropbox\DSI (His)\Windows Apps\Testing\C_sharp\C_dll>dir /s/b "..\\..\\..\\debug\\C_dll.dll" C_dll.vcxproj
W:\Dropbox\DSI (His)\Windows Apps\debug\C_dll.dll
W:\Dropbox\DSI (His)\Windows Apps\Testing\C_sharp\C_dll\C_dll.vcxproj

W:\Dropbox\DSI (His)\Windows Apps>dir /s/b "Debug\C_dll.dll" Apps.sln
W:\Dropbox\DSI (His)\Windows Apps\Debug\C_dll.dll
W:\Dropbox\DSI (His)\Windows Apps\Apps.sln
```

So I'm perplexed. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?????

The build output is:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: C_dll, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  C_dll.c
1>     Creating library W:\Dropbox\DSI (His)\Windows Apps\Debug\C_dll.lib and object W:\Dropbox\DSI (His)\Windows Apps\Debug\C_dll.exp
1>  C_dll.vcxproj -> W:\Dropbox\DSI (His)\Windows Apps\Debug\C_dll.dll
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Call_C, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>  Call_C -> W:\Dropbox\DSI (His)\Windows Apps\Testing\C_sharp\Call_C\bin\Debug\Call_C.exe
========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

The tree for my solution follows:

```
W:\DROPBOX
└───DSI
    └───Windows Apps
        ├───c_sharp_test
        │   ├───bin
        │   │   ├───Debug
        │   │   └───Release
        │   ├───obj
        │   │   └───Debug
        │   │       └───TempPE
        │   └───Properties
        └───Debug
```

The .sln file path is:

```
W:\Dropbox\DSI (His)\Windows Apps\Apps.sln
```

The two project paths are:

```
W:\Dropbox\DSI (His)\Windows Apps\Testing\C_sharp\Call_C\Call_C.csproj
W:\Dropbox\DSI (His)\Windows Apps\Testing\C_sharp\C_dll\C_dll.vcxproj
```

Comment: Personally, I'd use the first method, and then add it to the project as an "existing item" then set the build action to none, and the "Copy to Output Directory" as "Copy Always" or "Copy If Newer". The problem comes in if you change your directory structure even a little, your build will break, and if you ever move into source control, somebody else will not have the same folder structure.

Comment: Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx.

Answer (score 2):

this `[DllImport("C_dll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]`is correct. Just configure the output of C_dll.dll in the same directory of your EXE (Call_C.exe). In Visual Studio Go to Configuration Manager and Configure the  output directory of your C_dll.dll in Configuration properties/General

Comment: I went to Configuration Manager but it doesn't have a properties/General. Maybe you mean the properties of the project. So I went there for the dll project and there is an output section and that says "$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\". On the dll project, select Properties, under Configuration Properties click General, then Output Directory.

So I changed it to "$(ProjectDir)\..\Call_C\bin\$(Configuration)\". Then changed the import statement to "[DllImport("C_dll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]". Then did the same thing for the release configuration.

That works perfectly .... thanks.

Comment: @user3389362 yes that's what I wanted to say ... sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

I found that the search base is where the .EXE is so the import needs to be like this:

```
[DllImport("\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\Debug\\C_dll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
```

If anyone could suggest a way to force C_dll.dll to land where the .EXE is then I would really appreciate the information.

Thanks

Comment: See my comment about forcing it into the output directory of your application.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the best thing to do is set the "Build Action" to `None` and the "Copy to Output Directory" to `Copy Always` or `Copy if Newer`.

.Net uses an assembly loading schema called [Fusion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), this will look along an explicit path, locally (to the executing assembly), in the GAC and then along the path environment variable.  This logic can be different if your application is running from the internet or intranet.

FUSLOGVW would be a good tool to see where Fusion is looking to find your dll.  But, the simplest thing is to include your assemblies in the currently executing assembly folder.

Comment: Scott Hanselman has a good [blog post about FUSLOGVW](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately FUSLOGVW and assembly loading don't apply here, since the reference is not a project reference, but a p/invoke one. The DLL is not added as a project reference, its just referenced in code via `DLLImport`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't think about that.  @RonBeyer:  Your earlier comment about "Build Action" and "Copy Directory" are still valid.  Fusion rules are very similar to [Win32 LoadLibrary rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586%28VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  (minus the GAC of course).  So the advise of putting the dll next to the currently executing assembly is still a good one.

Comment: Where do I find "Build Action"? Can you please be more specific on how to navigate to the various places?